# Why do extern variable templates need no definition?

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables, extern

Recently, I struggled a bit with variable templates in C++ and found something that I do not understand. Suppose you have two **global variables** `a` and `b` which are declared as **extern** in a header file. The difference between those two is, that `b` is a **variable template** and `a` is **not**. Now, the thing I do not understand is, that `a` does need a **definition** but `b` does **not**.
So my **question** is, why does `b` need no definition but `a` does or rather why does the linker know, where `b` is defined? Can I **explicitly define** `b`? If yes, **where** and **how**?
Maybe I am doing something wrong, but the code compiles, links and runs correctly with the VC++ 2017 compiler if I test it.
Here is the related **code**:

```
// header.hpp
#pragma once

extern int a;

template<typename T>
extern T b;

// source.cpp    
#include "header.hpp"

int a; // definition of a, but definition of b is missing

// main.cpp
#include "header.hpp"

int main()
{
    a = 1;
    b<int> = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As any other template `b<int>` is automatically instantiated by the compiler as soon it's specialized.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, the other question answers all about functions templates. But how can I explicitly define/specialize `b` in the same as it is done with `a`. Plus how can I give it a value like I could with `a`?

Comment: The same applies for templated variables.